# Unable to connect to tor network using silvertunnel netlib in java

Tags: java, tor, silvertunnel

I am trying to connect to tor network to send anonymous HTTP requests. But it throws `IllegalBlockSizeException`. I have used `silvertunnel.org_netlib.jar`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // TODO code application logic here
             NetLayer lowerNetLayer = NetFactory.getInstance().getNetLayerById(NetLayerIDs.TOR); 

            lowerNetLayer.waitUntilReady();
            NetlibURLStreamHandlerFactory factory = new NetlibURLStreamHandlerFactory(false);
             factory.setNetLayerForHttpHttpsFtp(lowerNetLayer);
            String urlStr = "http://www.whatismyip.com/";
            URLStreamHandler handler = factory.createURLStreamHandler("http");
            URL context = null;
            URL url = new URL(context, urlStr, handler);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        //connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        //connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",  String.valueOf(postData.length()));

        // Write data
         OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();


        // Read response
        StringBuilder responseSB = new StringBuilder();
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
           responseSB.append(line);

        // Close streams
        br.close();
        os.close();
        Document doc=Jsoup.parse(responseSB.toString());

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }

    }
```

I got this error:

```
`WARNING: Directory.updateNetworkStatusNew Exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 256 bytes
    at org.silvertunnel.netlib.layer.tor.util.Encryption.verifySignature(Encryption.java:272)
    at org.silvertunnel.netlib.layer.tor.directory.DirectoryConsensus.<init>(DirectoryConsensus.java:117)
    at org.silvertunnel.netlib.layer.tor.directory.Directory.updateNetworkStatusNew(Directory.java:377)
    at org.silvertunnel.netlib.layer.tor.directory.Directory.refreshListOfServers(Directory.java:287)
    at org.silvertunnel.netlib.layer.tor.directory.DirectoryManagerThread.updateDirectory(DirectoryManagerThread.java:60)
    at org.silvertunnel.netlib.layer.tor.directory.DirectoryManagerThread.run(DirectoryManagerThread.java:76)
Caused by: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 256 bytes
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:337)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:382)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
    at org.silvertunnel.netlib.layer.tor.util.Encryption.verifySignature(Encryption.java:251)
    ... 5 more
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.setProperty('socksProxyHost','127.0.0.1');

System.setProperty('socksProxyPort','9051');

Add this two line in your main method and use [vidalia for tor](https://www.torproject.org/projects/vidalia.html.en)

Comment: use can also use Autoidetityswitcher for switch identity.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question but suggests a different tool and links to a dead site.